# TomlDecodeError during application deployment on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

I am attempting to deploy a Python application with Streamlit on Heroku. I have successfully deployed an app previously (which is still up), and am using the same setup.sh file and the same format for the Procfile (with the .py file name changed as the only difference.) When attempting to deploy the current app from my Github repository, I receive the following error:

TomlDecodeError: Key name found without value. Reached end of line.

I've tested what I can of my Python code outside of Heroku, minus the Streamlit parts which are there to provide drop-down menus, etc.

Repository is here: https://github.com/mattwilliams06/icsmodule3.git

Error trace from Heroku logs:

```
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179204+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179242+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/streamlit", line 7, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179334+00:00 app[web.1]:     from streamlit.cli import main
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179338+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/__init__.py", line 121, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179496+00:00 app[web.1]:     from streamlit.DeltaGenerator import DeltaGenerator as _DeltaGenerator
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179499+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/DeltaGenerator.py", line 33, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179628+00:00 app[web.1]:     from streamlit import caching
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179632+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/caching.py", line 38, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179781+00:00 app[web.1]:     from streamlit.hashing import CodeHasher
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179784+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/hashing.py", line 36, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179925+00:00 app[web.1]:     from streamlit.folder_black_list import FolderBlackList
2020-01-16T16:59:08.179927+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/folder_black_list.py", line 39, in <module>
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180064+00:00 app[web.1]:     if config.get_option("global.developmentMode"):
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180067+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/config.py", line 94, in get_option
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180227+00:00 app[web.1]:     parse_config_file()
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/config.py", line 877, in parse_config_file
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180570+00:00 app[web.1]:     _update_config_with_toml(file_contents, filename)
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180575+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/streamlit/config.py", line 799, in _update_config_with_toml
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180896+00:00 app[web.1]:     parsed_config_file = toml.loads(raw_toml)
2020-01-16T16:59:08.180900+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/toml/decoder.py", line 187, in loads
2020-01-16T16:59:08.181067+00:00 app[web.1]:     " Reached end of line.", original, i)
2020-01-16T16:59:08.181073+00:00 app[web.1]: toml.decoder.TomlDecodeError: Key name found without value. Reached end of line. (line 1 column 2 char 1)
```

Comment: Please post a link to your source code

Comment: Thanks. I've added a link to the Github repository. I have a testing .py file to make sure the problem isn't with the actual .py file.

Comment: Can you also send the stack trace?

Comment: I can,. It's from the logs on Heroku.

Comment: I am running into this same issue with the exact same error message.  In almost the exact same circumstance.  Anybody have answers on this?  Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanBechtel Have you found the solution? since I am also stuck at the same postion

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into the same issue and found an easy fix from the internet.
Just open `.streamlit` folder in *Users->(Your-PC-name)* and delete the only `toml` file present there. Then deploy the site without running again the streamlit app from your local. It got successfully deployed.