# TomlDecodeError: Key name found without value. Reached end of line When deploying on Heroku

Tags: heroku, streamlit

Am getting this error message when deploying a streamlit app to Heroku and do not know how to troubleshoot it.  I have deployed apps using this setup previously, and removing the `config.toml` file has always fixed it.  But this time is different.

I went to Heroku's website to find help and no luck so far:  https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/tomldecodeerror-key-name-found-without-value-reached-end-of-line-when-deploying-on-heroku/12285

It looks like this questions has left others hanging as well, since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59776115/tomldecodeerror-during-application-deployment-on-heroku) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65122192/getting-toml-decoder-tomldecodeerror-key-name-found-without-value-while-depl) have the same error message and there has not been an answer so far.

Here is my `setup.sh` file, which I believe is causing the problem:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"myemailgmail.com\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

Here is the application file itself, `app.py`:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import plotly.express as px

@st.cache
def load_data(n_rows=3000):
    data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JonathanBechtel/dat-02-22/main/ClassMaterial/Unit3/data/ks2.csv', nrows=n_rows)
    return data

@st.cache
def group_data(x_axis, y_axis):
    result = data.groupby(x_axis)[y_axis].mean()
    return result

@st.cache
def load_model():
    with open('mod.pkl', 'rb') as mod:
        pipe = pickle.load(mod)
        
    return pipe

st.title("Understanding Kickstarter Applications -- See How Easy It Is Cindy?")

section = st.sidebar.radio('Section', ['Data Explorer', 'Model Predictions'])

n_rows = st.sidebar.number_input("Enter Number of Rows To Load", min_value=1000, max_value=100000, step=1000)
data = load_data(n_rows)
if section == 'Data Explorer':
    chart_type = st.sidebar.selectbox('Chart Type', ['Bar', 'Line', 'Strip'])
    
    st.write(data)
    
    x_axis = st.sidebar.selectbox('Choose Column for X-Axis', ['category',  'main_category', 'country'])
    y_axis = st.sidebar.selectbox('Choose Column for y-axis', ['state', 'goal'])
    
    st.header(f"Average value for {y_axis} for column {x_axis}")

    if chart_type == 'Bar':
        result = group_data(x_axis, y_axis)
        st.bar_chart(result)
    elif chart_type == 'Line':
        result = group_data(x_axis, y_axis)
        st.line_chart(result)
    else:
        result = data[[x_axis, y_axis]]
        st.plotly_chart(px.strip(result, x=x_axis, y=y_axis, color=x_axis))
        
elif section == 'Model Predictions':
    with open('mod.pkl', 'rb') as mod:
        pipe = pickle.load(mod)
    print(pipe)
    category       = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select A Category', data['category'].unique().tolist())
    main_category  = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a Main Category', data['main_category'].unique().tolist())
    funding_amount = st.sidebar.number_input('Enter Your Funding Amount', min_value=0, value=1000, step=500) 
    
    sample = pd.DataFrame({
        'category': [category],
        'main_category': [main_category],
        'funding_amount': [funding_amount]
        })
    
    
    prediction = pipe.predict_proba(sample)
    
    st.header(f"Predicted Probability of Campaign Successs: {prediction[0][1]:.2%}")
```

My `requirements.txt` file reads like this:

```
streamlit == 0.67.0
scikit-learn
pandas
category_encoders == 2.*
xgboost == 1.3.*
protobuf == 3.13.0
plotly == 4.12.0
```

Any recommendations are welcome, because all wells have been run dry at this point.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? I am having the same issue and tried nearly everything

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "[server]\nheadless = true\nport = $PORT\nenableCORS = false\n" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml